# display problem of an expo application on ipad devices

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ipad, expo

I am developing an application using Expo and I have noticed an issue when trying to view it on iPads. The application appears in the format of a mobile phone instead of adapting correctly to the iPad's screen size.

I have checked various settings in my project, but I have not been able to resolve the issue. Here are some of the things I have tried so far:

I verified the settings in app.json and made sure that the "orientation" property is correctly configured.

I ensured that I am using Viewports correctly in React Native.

I reviewed the package.json file to make sure there are no incorrect configurations affecting the display on iPad.

I made sure that the styles are generic and adaptable to different screen sizes.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this behavior and how I could fix it?

I appreciate any suggestions or advice you can provide. Thank you!

Below, I am showing how the application looks, keeping in mind that the entire black background is part of the iPad screen:

[image: Aplicación en ipad]

I've noticed that Instagram has the same configuration on iPads. It looks like this on Instagram:

[image: Instagram en ipad]